# Adding a Custom API Function After Shopify Checkout

Tags: api, e-commerce, shopify

I am trying to implement a way to capture a customer's account information, product information, and purchase information whenever they do a checkout. I'm planning to use this information to do a POST request into my own separate database.

I wanted to know if it is possible to go into the code for checkout and implement this? Does this require a specfic plan to be on and would I have access to modify the checkout code?

Thanks for your assistance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This just requires setting up a private app and installing a web hook.

A private app lets you set up access keys for using the API. In your store:

- click Apps
- In the upper right of the App page click "Private Apps"
- upper right again click "Create Private App"

For the web hooks see: https://docs.shopify.com/api/reference/webhook

Comment: Thanks! The web hook is what I really needed.

Answer (score 0):

- You can use webhook like "bknights" mentioned above.
- But there's a note: you just only capture order-information AFTER customer complete checkout successfully. So there's no way to capture unless customer complete current checkout.
- More... on the link https://docs.shopify.com/api/reference/webhook: you can see hooks for Checkouts "create/delete/update", NOT a hook like "type on checkout".